# Code Can't pass java blue j testerfile but no error is shown in code

Tags: java, arrays, performance, junit, bluej

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Q10Q {
    public static List<Integer> sumOfDistinctCubes(int n) {
        // Find largest n
        int c = 1;
        while ((c * c * c) <= n) {
            c++;
        }

        LinkedList<Integer> soFar = new LinkedList<>();
        sumOfDistinctCubes(n, c, soFar);
        return soFar;
    }

    private static boolean sumOfDistinctCubes(int n, int c, LinkedList<Integer> soFar) {
        if (n == 0)
            return true;

        if (n < 0)
            return false;

        if (c == 0)
            return true;

        soFar.addLast(c);
        int cCube = c * c * c;
        boolean result = sumOfDistinctCubes(n - cCube, (n - cCube >= cCube) ? c : c - 1, soFar);
        if (result) {
            return true;
        } else {
            soFar.removeLast();
            return sumOfDistinctCubes(n, c - 1, soFar);
        }

    }
```

[image1[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvMP4.png)

This is what is required I have come up with this code however i am unable to pass the tester file and it just wont load. My codes are able to pass there testers however this code takes forever and just ends up failing I have anaylized but haven't been able to figure things out.. This code is trying to find the sumofdistinct cubes

Comment: Is it failing for every n, as small as 1 or failing for some larger values?